# How to deal with whitespace in object attributes?

Tags: javascript

```
{
    "cities" : {
        "San Francisco" : {
            "location Name" : "San Francisco, CA",
            "data" : "51.1"
        },

        "San Jose" : {
            "location Name" : "San Jose, CA",
            "data" : "52.5"
        }
    }
}
```

how to get San Jose, CA?

`myJSON.cities.['San Jose'].[location name]` doesn't work

how to get 52.5?
`myJSON.cities.['San Jose'].data`?

Comment: *"How to deal with whitespace in JSON?"* JSON ignores it, so you should too.

Comment: You're already half there with `myJSON.cities.['San Jose'].[location name]` - just use quotation marks on `'location name'` like you already did for `'San Jose'`.

Comment: You should really take a hard look and figure out if yo actually need those spaces in the first place

Comment: i mean, i can just do myJSON.cities.san jose.data, so I was wondering about the syntax of dealing with white-space on Google but did not find any.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @nnnnnn missing the '' was a typo, but adding those does not help

Comment: I just noticed you haven't matched the case either: you've an uppercase "N" in "location Name" in your object, but not in the code that accesses it. Is that a typo too? And regarding your other comment, there's no way `myJSON.cities.san jose.data` will work: you definitely can _not_ have spaces in dot notation.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, sorry about the type, I made up the example quickly, my questions was just how to deal with space in JSON?  I am aware of that `myJSON.cities.san jose.data` will not work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do *both* attribute access *and* indexing. Pick one or the other.

```
myJSON.cities['San Jose']['location Name']
```

The second is allowed, since each object is accessed independently.

Comment: @JJLiu - Did you try it? `myJSON.cities.['San Jose'].data` or `myJSON.cities.['San Jose']['data']` should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
myJSON.cities['San Jose']['location Name']
```